# Mocking UriInfo using Mockito and the response is not as expected

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to mock UriInfo object to pass to a restful service method , the response should be List if successul request with the correct QueryParams, and StatusResponse in case of any error  or failure happened, I am sending a correct request but the controller receives it as If I sent a wrong request with no QueryParams , and gives me a Status Response Object.

RestController.java

Service method:

```
public Response getObjectives(@Context UriInfo info) {
try {

return Response.ok(objectiveService.getObjectives(info.getQueryParameters())).build();

} catch (Exception e) {
return Response.status(Status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).entity(StatusResponse.EXPIRED_SESSION).build();
}
}
```

RestControllerTest.java

```
private UriInfo mockUriInfo(String uri) throws URISyntaxException {
UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
Mockito.when(uriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(new URI(uri));
return uriInfo;
}


@Test
@DataSet({ "/datasets/object_target_type.xml", "/datasets/st_objective_levels.xml", "/datasets/st_objectives.xml", "/datasets/st_related_objectives.xml" })
@Transactional(TransactionMode.ROLLBACK)
public void testGetObjectives() throws Exception {
UriInfo uriInfo = mockUriInfo("http://localhost:8080/v1.0/objectives?planId=987&level=2");
Response response = restController.getObjectives(uriInfo);
Object objs = response.getEntity();

ReflectionAssert.assertLenientEquals(objs, Arrays.asList(
    new Objective(2L, "Obj1", new Level(2L), 987L, new TargetType(1L), 222d, 3),
    new Objective(3L, "Obj2", new Level(2L), 987L, new TargetType(1L), 333d, 3),
    new Objective(5L, "Obj5", new Level(2L), 987L, new TargetType(1L), 555d, 3),
    new Objective(6L, "Obj6", new Level(2L), 654L, new TargetType(1L), 666d, 3))
                    );

}
```

But the actual response is a StatusResponse as if an exception was thrown in the RestController method.

I think it failed to mock the UriInfo and it doesn't see the QueryParams.

Help me, whats wrong with mocking the UriInfo object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you get a null pointer exception because you didn't mock `getQueryParameters()`.

Your mocking code might look something like this (I've made things a bit less concise for clarity):

```
private UriInfo mockUriInfo(String uri) throws URISyntaxException {
    UriInfo uriInfo = Mockito.mock(UriInfo.class);
    URI uriObject = new URI(uri);
    Mockito.when(uriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(uriObject);
    Map<String,String> queryParametersMap = this.parseQueryParameters(uriObject.getQuery());
    Mockito.when(uriInfo.getQueryParameters()).thenReturn(new MultivaluedHashMap(queryParametersMap));
    return uriInfo;
}

private Map<String,String> parseQueryParameters(String query) {
    String[] params = query.split("&");
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String param : params)
    {
        String[] pair = param.split("=");
        String name = pair[0];
        String value = pair[1];
        map.put(name, value);
    }
    return map;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was really mistaken, your example is very clear and I got it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please flag my answer as accepted (by clicking on the grayed-out checkmark), since it seems to have solved your issue.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much how to use stackoverflow to ask questions, I used to search for questions on it only