# How to mock requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters() from Jersey in java

Tags: java, unit-testing, filter, jersey, mockito

I have written one jersey request filter and I want to unit test this. Below is the code.

```
@Override
public void filter(ContainerRequestContext containerRequestContext) throws IOException {
    logPathParameters(containerRequestContext);
}
private void logPathParameters(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) {
    StringBuilder parameterStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters = requestContext.getUriInfo().getPathParameters();   
    if(!pathParameters.isEmpty()) {
        Iterator iterator = pathParameters.keySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            String name = iterator.next().toString();
            String paramValue = pathParameters.getFirst(name);
            String shortParamName = getShortNameForPathParameter(name);
            parameterStringBuilder.append(String.format("paramName: %s, paramValue: %s; ", shortParamName, paramValue));
        }
        if (parameterStringBuilder.length() > 0) {
            MDC.put("pathParam ", parameterStringBuilder.toString());
            System.out.println(parameterStringBuilder.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

To unit test above filter function I have to mock ContainerRequestContext. So I created below function.

```
private ContainerRequestContext mockContainerRequest(String uri)
  throws URISyntaxException
  {
    ContainerRequestContext requestContext = mock(ContainerRequestContext.class);
    UriInfo uriInfo = mock(UriInfo.class);
    URI requestUri = new URI(uri);
    when(uriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(requestUri);
    when(requestContext.getUriInfo()).thenReturn(uriInfo);
    return requestContext;
}
```

Here I want to mock getPathParameters of uriInfo, this will return path parameter present in the input uri string to this function.
Is there any utility function which can do this for me. Like if I pass url to it, it should return me the MultivaluedMap of path Parameters.

Something similar mentioned in the answer of below question.

[example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096241/mocking-uriinfo-using-mockito-and-the-response-is-not-as-expected)

This is done for query parameters. I want to do it for path Parameters. I don't want to build it manually. Some kind of utility function should be good.

Comment: If you are asking for a utility function then this question is off-topic. If you have tried to solve it yourself and come upon an issue, then [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: But i believe that you are forgetting that it is just a mock so you can basically make it return what ever map you want for your test

Answer (score 0):

If coming up with an algorithm is proving to be a roadblock then just make a fake map to represent the path parameters.

```
private ContainerRequestContext mockContainerRequest(String uri, MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters) throws URISyntaxException {
    ContainerRequestContext requestContext = mock(ContainerRequestContext.class);
    UriInfo uriInfo = mock(UriInfo.class);
    URI requestUri = new URI(uri);
    when(uriInfo.getRequestUri()).thenReturn(requestUri);
    when(uriInfo..getPathParameters()).thenReturn(pathParameters);
    when(requestContext.getUriInfo()).thenReturn(uriInfo);

    return requestContext;
}
```

from there when arranging the test you can populate it with segments that represent/match the test uri.

Comment: You passed MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters as a function parameter to  mockContainerRequest function. I dont want this. I need an  another function which will take uri as a input parameter and return MultivaluedMap<String, String> pathParameters as a output. which I will use in mockContainerRequest function